# Proguard Issue with gson and jackson

Tags: android, android-studio, jackson, gson, proguard

I'm not using jackson in my project. I'm only using gson library and still when I'm trying to build release apk, proguard shows lots of warnings.

Here are the warnings:-

```
Warning:org.immutables.gson.adapter.ExpectedSubtypesAdapter$JsonParserReaderSupplier: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer
Warning:org.immutables.gson.adapter.FieldNamingTranslator: can't find referenced class sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$GsonProviderOptions: can't find referenced class org.immutables.value.Value$Immutable
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$GsonProviderOptions: can't find referenced class org.immutables.value.Value$Style
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$GsonProviderOptions: can't find referenced class org.immutables.value.Value$Style$ImplementationVisibility
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$GsonProviderOptions: can't find referenced class org.immutables.value.Value
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$GsonProviderOptions: can't find referenced class org.immutables.value.Value$Immutable
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$GsonProviderOptions: can't find referenced class org.immutables.value.Value$Style
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$GsonProviderOptions: can't find referenced class org.immutables.value.Value$Style$ImplementationVisibility
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser$Feature
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator$Feature
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser$Feature
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator$Feature
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider$JacksonStreamer: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonGeneratorWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
Warning:org.immutables.gson.stream.JsonParserReader$2: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
Warning:org.parceler.ParcelAnnotationProcessor: can't find referenced method 'void init(javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment)' in program class org.parceler.transfuse.AnnotationProcessorBase
Warning:org.parceler.ParcelAnnotationProcessor: can't find referenced class com.google.auto.service.AutoService
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor: can't find referenced method 'void setName(java.lang.String)' in program class org.parceler.apache.commons.beanutils.MappedPropertyDescriptor
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.parceler.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.parceler.apache.log4j.Category
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.parceler.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.parceler.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.parceler.apache.log4j.Category
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.parceler.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.parceler.apache.log4j.Priority
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.parceler.apache.log4j.Logger
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.parceler.apache.log.Hierarchy
Warning:org.parceler.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.parceler.apache.log.Logger
Warning:org.parceler.codemodel.util.SingleByteEncoder: can't find referenced class sun.nio.cs.Surrogate$Parser
Warning:org.parceler.codemodel.util.SingleByteEncoder: can't find referenced class sun.nio.cs.Surrogate
Warning:org.parceler.codemodel.util.SingleByteEncoder: can't find referenced class sun.nio.cs.Surrogate$Parser
Warning:org.parceler.codemodel.util.SingleByteEncoder: can't find referenced class sun.nio.cs.Surrogate
Warning:org.parceler.codemodel.util.SingleByteEncoder: can't find referenced class sun.nio.cs.Surrogate$Parser
Warning:org.parceler.guava.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.parceler.guava.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.parceler.guava.cache.Striped64$Cell: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.parceler.guava.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.parceler.guava.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.bootstrap.BootstrapProcessor: can't find referenced field 'javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv' in program class org.parceler.transfuse.bootstrap.BootstrapProcessor
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.gen.FilerResourceWriter: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileManager$Location
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.gen.FilerResourceWriter: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileManager
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.gen.FilerResourceWriter: can't find referenced class javax.tools.StandardLocation
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.gen.FilerResourceWriter: can't find referenced class javax.tools.FileObject
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.gen.FilerSourceCodeWriter: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.util.MessagerLogger: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.util.MessagerLogger: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.util.MessagerLogger: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.validation.Validator: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.validation.Validator: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.validation.Validator: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.validation.Validator$ValidationBuilder: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.validation.Validator$ValidationBuilder: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic
Warning:org.parceler.transfuse.validation.Validator$ValidationBuilder: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind
```

here is my complete proguard file

```
# Apache
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.**

# ButterKnife 7

-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

# Crashlytics 1.+

-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Deeplink dispatch
-keep class com.airbnb.deeplinkdispatch.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * { @com.airbnb.deeplinkdispatch.DeepLink <methods>;}

# Configuration for Fabric Twitter Kit
# See: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.**
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* *;
}

# Facebook 3.2

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature

## Google Play Services 4.3.23 specific rules ##
## https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard ##

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

## GSON 2.2.4 specific rules ##

# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# MoPub Proguard Config
# NOTE: You should also include the Android Proguard config found with the build tools:
# $ANDROID_HOME/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt

# Keep public classes and methods.
-keepclassmembers class com.mopub.** { public *; }
-keep public class com.mopub.**
-keep public class android.webkit.JavascriptInterface {}

# Explicitly keep any custom event classes in any package.
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBanner {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventInterstitial {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.nativeads.CustomEventNative {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesBanner {}
-keep class * extends com.mopub.nativeads.AvocarrotNativeMopub {}

# Support for Android Advertiser ID.
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info {*;}

# Simple-fb
-keep class com.sromku.simple.fb.entities.** { *; }

# OkHttp
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

## Square Otto specific rules ##
## https://square.github.io/otto/ ##

# Otto
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;
    @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;
}

## Square Picasso specific rules ##
## https://square.github.io/picasso/ ##

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

# Retrofit 1.X

-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn rx.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

# If in your rest service interface you use methods with Callback argument.
-keepattributes Exceptions

# If your rest service methods throw custom exceptions, because you've defined an ErrorHandler.
-keepattributes Signature

# Also you must note that if you are using GSON for conversion from JSON to POJO representation, you must ignore those POJO classes from being obfuscated.
# Here include the POJO's that have you have created for mapping JSON response to POJO for example.

-keep class com.myproject.model.** { *; }

# Android design
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

# app specific
-keepclassmembers class com.myproject.** {
   public *;
}

# Removing logs
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}

# Keep the support library

-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
## ---------------- End Project specifics ---------------- ##
```

Please help, how do fix it.

Comment: can you post your progaurd file? we can not say anything if you have added rules or not in proguard without seeing it.

Comment: @Shvet I've added my complete proguard config

Comment: try @human123's solution, as you already have added necessary rule.

Comment: @Shvet got it working by adding "parceler" library and adding "-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**"

Answer (score 2):

If you are still getting error after adding keepattributes line as suggested by Emanuel Seidinger, please add dontwarn directive for packages causing issues.

-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**

Comment: got it working by adding "parceler" library and adding "-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**"

Answer (score 1):

I would attack the problem with a different angle. What I see here is that warnings you provided might indicate unintended leakage of compilation-only artifacts to the actual compile/runtime classpath which is processed by ProGuard.
In particular, annotation processors (such as `ParcelAnnotationProcessor`) and optional annotations should not be included in the regular compilation scope.

Usually what you can do is to set scope of such dependencies to `provided` or `compileOnly` depending on the apt plugin you use (assuming you use Gradle to build android app)

As one of the authors of `org.immutables` libraries I already faced and discussed some difficulties with a ProGuard which might do not recognize special compile-only scopes etc. In your particular case you use `org.immutables:gson` artifact which contains optional Jackson-Gson integration bridge classes which are propagated to build. You usually do not need those classes on Android. As a solution I would suggest to just replace `org.immutables:gson` artifact with annotation-only version available using `annotations` classifier (using like `provided "org.immutables:gson:2.1.11:annotations"`). This artifact excludes any unwanted Jackson-dependent classes.
See sample Gradle configuration when using Immutables annotation processor: http://immutables.github.io/getstarted.html#android

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using GSON in an Android project. You can try the proguard configuration found here [android-proguard-example](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg). You have to adapt the last line in the example for the model classes in your project which will be serialized using GSON.
I do have the following lines in my proguard config because of GSON:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```